# Postgres (8.0.2., Redshift) SQL function definition, error "The cursor is not located inside a statement"

Tags: function, amazon-redshift, function-declaration

I am a super noob in postgresql. But I need to define a func that would `map: int --> datetime`
After reading documentation I've come up with this:

```
 CREATE FUNCTION fut(num integer) RETURNS datetime
 -- convert a UNIX time integer into the datetime timestamp
    AS $$ select timestamp 'epoch'+interval '1 second'*num; $$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql;

select fut(500);
```

But it returns

```
The cursor is not located inside a statement!
```

Could you please point me to what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you on a really old PostgreSQL version? That `CREATE FUNCTION` should've failed because the function body is completely malformed; you've written an SQL function but declared it `plpgsql`. You should get `ERROR:  type "datetime" does not exist` and if you fix that, you should get `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "select"`.

Comment: I've got 8.0.2. Could you please give me a short advice what it wrong with it?

Comment: 8.0.2? Wow. Time to upgrade to something less prehistoric. If you're using an ancient PostgreSQL you **must** mention it in your questions, because answers will assume you have access to features, functions, syntax etc introduced in the last **ten years**. If you are actually using a fork like Redshift, it's even more important to say so since they tend to be heavily modified. As for the function: There is no `datetime` data type in PostgreSQL, use `timestamp`. Declare the function `sql` not `plpgsql`. The `to_timestamp` built-in function does what you want on current PostgreSQL versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I knew Redshift doesn't even permit user-defined functions. Yeah: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-features.html : *User-defined functions and stored procedures*. So I think you're plain out of luck.

A search for *Redshift epoch to timestamp* or *redshift `to_timestamp`* finds that lots of other people have looked into this already:

- http://yiyujia.blogspot.com.au/2014/04/redshift-convert-integer-to-timestamp.html
- http://www.valkrysa.com/tech/2015/1/30/amazon-redshift-converting-unix-epoch-time-into-timestamps

etc.

The most sensible answers are those that rely on:

```
TIMESTAMP 'epoch' + myunixtime * INTERVAL '1 Second '
```

which is what you appear to be already doing. This the best you are going to get, because Redshift does not support user-defined functions.

Comment: Thank you for such detailed clarifications Craig!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand from your function, you want to convert [unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (i.e., the number of seconds since 00:00:00 UTC, 1 January 1970) saved as a value of integer type, to a value of valid [postgresql date/time](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-datetime.html) type.

If this is so, you do not have to create a new function for such a conversion, just use the predefined postgresql function [to_timestamp](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-datetime.html),  for example:

```
# select to_timestamp(500);
to_timestamp      
------------------------
 1970-01-01 03:08:20+03
(1 row)
```

Comment: It does not seem to exist in 8.0.2. So I am bound to define my own func.

Comment: @AVX Using 8.0.2 is something you mention *when you ask the question*. It's bit like coming along and saying "Hey, Chrome won't install on my computer" and when asked what the computer is, you mention it's a 486 running Windows 95.

Comment: Thanks, Craig. Updated in the question. Cool analogy though :)